# How fullpage to switch on/off when resize page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullpage.js

Somebody know if it possible to **switch on fullpage() when window.width > 700**,
and switch it off when window.width less 700.

I need to switch off it on tablets and mobile.

mine wrong solution

```
`https://codepen.io/liashok/pen/ERXozv?editors=1111`
```

and error

> "fullPage: Fullpage.js can only be initialized once and you are doing it multiple times!"

Comment: Feel sorry for those with a window width of exactly 700,..

Answer (score 0):

You're going to need to track the state in a variable (whether it's been attached or not) and destroy the fullpage effect if you cross the boundary from >700 to <= 700. Try this.

```js
$(function(){
  var attached = false;//track it's current state
  manageFullPage();

  $(window).resize( function() {
    manageFullPage();
  } )

  function manageFullPage(){
    if( $(this).width() > 700 ) {
      if(! attached){
        $('#fullpage').fullpage();
        attached = true;//note it's been attached
      }
    }else{//we don't want fullpage. destroy it if it's attached
      if(attached){
        attached = false;//mark destroyed
        $.fn.fullpage.destroy('all');
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}
.section {
  border: 1px solid red;
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullPage.js/2.7.8/jquery.fullPage.js"></script>
<div id="fullpage">
  <div class="section"></div>
  <div class="section"></div>
  <div class="section"></div>
  <div class="section"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

it was very simple, just type this:

```
$('#fullPage').fullpage({
        responsive: 700 // here is solution
})
```

=D

Comment: This doesnt actually disable fullpage as you can still see all its classes on elements